# Docker create volume with file host to override container file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am new to docker and learning from the online resources.Basically I have an angularjs project that contains a conf file in folder (src/assets/conf/appConfig.json) and basically what  I am trying to achieve  is when I run my docker (version - 19.03.8)  command the
fileappConfig.json should be copied from `/var/lib/docker/volumes/volumetest/_data/appConfig.json` to
`src/assets/conf/appConfig.json`.

I have created a volume(volumetest) as shown below:

[image]

I have two questions:

What command do I need in order to create file appConfig.json in the path /var/lib/docker/volumes/volumetest/_data and add the following line in the file:

{
baseUrl:http://localhost:8080/
}

Once the above is created  I will add the following line in my Dockerfile for angularjs project:

```
COPY src/assets/conf/appConfig.json /var/lib/docker/volumes/volumetest/_data
```

Will the file src/assets/conf/appConfig.json be overridden when i do docker run command (docker run -p 8000:8080 -d --name cm testApp:1.0)?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should completely ignore the `/var/lib/docker` tree.  Instead, you can use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to replace the file at startup time.  Create the file on your host; let's say you've created an alternate `appConfig.json` in the current directory.  When you run your container, mount that file in:

```sh
docker run \
  -v $PWD/appConfig.json:/app/src/assets/conf/appConfig.json \
  ... \
  testApp:1.0
```

The contents of `/var/lib/docker` are installation-specific and aren't intended to be directly edited.  Also, since containers and images have isolated filesystem spaces, you can't write directly into a host directory in a `Dockerfile`.  If you used a named volume, you'd only be able to edit the file from inside a container, and you'd have to replace the entire `conf` directory with the volume contents.